# YIELD formula of Excel in Java

Tags: groovy, excel-formula, jvm, finance

Is there any way of replicating the Excel YIELD formula in Java? I was able to calculate the IRR formula and I have the same results in Excel.

However, for the YIELD formula, I was not able to replicate exactly the same results. From what I have seen, there are different examples, but they have different parameters.

I would like to replicate exactly the same of Excel.

Please find the example I have used:

```
def BondYieldNewton(def price , def faceValue, def periods, def rate, def years){


    def oldYield = 0
    def yield = 0.1

    def presentValue = 0.00
    def presentValueDerivate = 0.00

    def tolerance = 1E-16
    while (tolerance < Math.abs(yield - oldYield)) {

        oldYield = yield
        for(int i = 1; i < periods * years; i++) {
            presentValue += (rate / periods) * faceValue / Math.pow((1 + oldYield / periods), i)
        }
        presentValue += faceValue / Math.pow((1 + oldYield), periods) - price

        for(int i = 1; i < periods * years; i++) {

            presentValueDerivate += -i * (rate / periods) * faceValue / Math.pow((1 + oldYield / periods), years * i + 1) - years * periods * faceValue / Math.pow((1 + oldYield / years), years * periods + 1)

        }
        yield = oldYield - presentValue / presentValueDerivate


    }
    return yield
}
```

These are some parameters:

```
        def price = 90
        def faceValue = 100;
        def years = 12;
        def period = 2
        def rate = 0.07
```

Thank you in advance,

Kat

UPDATE: Please find the formula I am trying to replicate and the update in the Groovy code
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-finance/chapter/valuing-bonds/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: Is this Groovy? Also, please show us the formula in Excel and the different results in Excel and here.